# Property of Newton step for self-concordant convex functions

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Suppose $f(x)$ is a convex and self-concordant function minimized at $x^*$. I have two starting points $\tilde{x}_0$ and $\hat{x}_0$ such that $|\hat{x}_0-x^*| \le |\tilde{x}_0 - x^*|$. We also know that $sign(\hat{x}_0 - x^*) = sign(\tilde{x}_0 - x^*)$. This obviously means that $f(\hat{x}_0) \le f(\tilde{x}_0)$.

We perform one Newton step to each initial point, obtaining $\hat{x}_1 = \hat{x}_0 - f'(\hat{x}_0)/f''(\hat{x}_0)$ and $\tilde{x}_1 = \tilde{x}_0 - f'(\tilde{x}_0)/f''(\tilde{x}_0)$. Will we still have $|\hat{x}_1-x^*| \le |\tilde{x}_1 - x^*|$ and thus $f(\hat{x}_1) \le f(\tilde{x}_1)$?

Comment: I don't see how you can conclude $f(\hat{x}_0) \le f(\tilde{x}_0)$ unless you know $\text{sign}(\hat{x}_0-x^*)= \text{sign} (\tilde{x}_0 - x^*)$.

Comment: It's not true for multivariate functions (substituting a norm for absolute values), so I agree with @p.s, it's not obvious for univariate ones. For clarity it would probably be best to assume the signs are the same.

Comment: Thanks for the correction! Yes, this is just for univariate functions where $\hat{x}_0$ is between $\tilde{x}_0$ and $x^*$.